# What is this large bronze medallion?

Tags: europe, poland, nobility, heraldry, german

[image: large medallion 3inch diameter with rampant lion on red shield Heraldry]

Searched many sites but nothing matches this particular lion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen some kind of medal(lion)(no pun intended) looking like that and it was the lion of Flandres for the rank of Chevalier or similar. Can't remember exactly though but it might be a starting point.

Comment: The basic structure is the 'five-armed Maltese Asterisk', often associated with [Legion of Honor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Honour#:~:text=The%20badge%20of%20the%20L%C3%A9gion%20is%20shaped%20as%20a%20five,oak%20wreath%20between%20the%20arms.) awards.

Comment: The heraldic description of the arms is "Gules, a lion rampant argent" (on red, a white lion standing) which is strangely unpopular, the reverse (red lion on white) being more common

Comment: According to [this](https://www.psu.edu/news/research/story/gules-crusily-and-fess-dancetty-or/) those were the arms of the Guardian (regent) of Scotland in the 14th century, so perhaps an association with Scotland.

Comment: This white lion does not seem to be of Polish origin. Looks more British or French.
While there are some overgrown heraldic cats spread around Silesia/Czechia, their design does not match. 
Additionally, white on red tend to be reserved for eagle in Poland so that's probably wrong country to look for.

Comment: Wow! You folks are amazing so many great leads to chase down. My biggest hurdle trying to track it down has been the lion's tail so many are much more elaborate or curve the wrong way. Thanks again I'll keep you posted

Comment: @OldPadawan It's definitely not a Flemish lion.

Comment: @Jos: couldn't do it on sunday but a [quick](https://www.p-degreef.com/fr/chevalier-de-l-ordre-royal-du-lion.html) [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=medaille+chevalier+lion+des+flandres) will help narrow down and (in)validate I believe.

Comment: I have found ebay listing for something with same lion shape on field of same shape https://www.ebay.com/itm/Authentic-US-Army-UNKNOWN-28th-Infantry-Regiment-DI-DUI-Unit-Crest-Insignia/184074825728
Image-searching for just snip of just a lion on Bing also yielded some Pinterest/Etsy listings with same/similar generic lion, but no details.

Comment: The elaborate tail is not actually "normal" - to the extent that the Bohemian lion's double tail was designed to *distinguish it* from all the other ones. See one of the answers here for a list of heraldic lions and their tails: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12661/symbolism-of-lion-with-forked-tail. Additionally these lions would have distinguishing crowns or colored claws (armed)/tongue (langued). This lion is armed and langued argent just like the body so it's not remarked upon.